# Mixed gender education is haram, what should I do?

Tags: fiqh, non-mahram, education

I will enter university next year, Inshallah. But, the problem in my country is that there are no separate gender universities and I don't want to go to any other country. What should I do? Also, I am currently in a mixed gender school. What should I do?

Comment: May I ask how you came onto gender mixed education is Haram?

Comment: Why should you change school? As long as you don't have bad thoughts everything will be Okay! And don't stress yourself too much.We are all Humans............

Comment: Avoid talking to guys unless necessary. Just limit the interaction. There will be many girls that you can stay with.

Comment: @zohal I am a boy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why many think free-mixing of the sexes is verboten?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/why-many-think-free-mixing-of-the-sexes-is-verboten)

Comment: oh..ok. Then stay away from the girls and stay with the guys.

Comment: @zohal Is talking with them outside of school make my diploma Haram?

Comment: It does not make your diploma haram but it is haram for male to talk to a female or for a female to talk to a male if they are not their mahram (unless it is necessary). I would say avoid unnecessary interactions as much s possible. You can't help what is not your fault and Allah is most Merciful.     I don't really see why you would need to interact outside of school. Also if you explain to your tutor they can help make sure you are partnered with males during group work. :)

Comment: @Zohal I befriended them, that's why.

Comment: Speaking with a woman to whom one is not related (i.e., not mahram) should only be for a specific need, such as asking a question, buying or selling, asking about the head of the household, and so on. Such conversations should be brief, with nothing doubtful in either what is said or how it is said.

Comment: befriending a non mahram can be dangerous because of the fitna which can lead to more and more sins.

Comment: @Zohal What I am asking is that making them my friends and/or not lowering my gaze in or out of school make my education haram?

Comment: As I said before it does not affect your education however it is a sin as we are always told to lower our gaze.

Comment: @Zohal This is my last question, but what about befriending, does it affect it?

Comment: Islamically girls and guys should not mix so befriend is not ideal. If contact is made it should on be on a professional level and not for social purposes.

Comment: @Zohal Does befriending them at school in a social level make my Diploma Haram though? That's what I want to know.

Comment: @HüdaverdiAlperenDemirok, regarding it doesn't seem that befriending them at school in a social level make your diploma haram/ Meanwhile, if there can be some minor sins in your being friend... = has its negative effect in the DoomsDays, not to make your diploma haram... / Well done mate, it indicates how much it is significant for you...

Answer (score 2):

> Mixed gender education is haram, what should I do?

First of all I appreciate your paying attention to this matter which made you making research concerning what you should do. Since it is seen that there could be diverse fields of sin in such positions.

Secondly, it doesn’t seem to be haram directly for students to educate in mixed gender location, I think; But as much as I know, according to the viewpoint of Shia-Islam (and probably Sunni view, although I am not exactly aware about Sunni view):

It would be haram if your attendance in those classes leads to sin or perhaps at least the introduction or the start the fields of commiting sin(s).

Thirdly as the final issue, you ought to leave it if you assume it would take you in sin position, otherwise it will be OK it if there is not introduction of sin(s).  Besides, don’t forget that education (at least in high degree) is not wajib that … Then the consent of Allah would be better than obtaining higher degree. Meanwhile Allah will give you more success in your life if you ignore it due to Him.

و من الله توفیق   / God Bless You

Comment: Thanks, I'm a Sunni though. Zohal and American Muslim already gave me the answer. Zohal told me that it isn't Haram in my thread. American Muslim told that it wasn't Haram in someone else's thread

Comment: uh-huh, nice. Hopefully you've found out what you want to do. Good luck mate.